# Testing a ruby module class method not working

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby module like this:

```rb
module SomeModule
  module Account
    def self.account_info
      raise NotImplementedError
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my test:

```
  describe ExchangeClientWrapper::Account do
    let(:mock_class) do
      class MockClass
        extend SomeModule::Account
      end
    end

    describe ".account_info" do
      it "raises a NotImplementedError" do
        expect { mock_class.account_info }.to raise_error(NotImplementedError)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
 expected NotImplementedError, got #<NoMethodError: undefined method `account_info' for MockClass:Class> with backtrace:
```

What is going on?

Does this not work:

```rb
module A
    module B
      def self.d
        puts "hi there"
      end
    end
end

class C
    extend A::B
end

C.d
```

But it appears this works:

```
 module A
    module B
      def self.d
        puts "hi there"
      end
    end
end

class C
    include A
end

C::B.d
```

Comment: I am thinking about the way you are naming the method (`self.d`) and trying to extend it is generating trouble. I had a read at https://medium.com/@leo_hetsch/ruby-modules-include-vs-prepend-vs-extend-f09837a5b073 maybe that helps you out?

Comment: The other thing, that I should just discard because I believe is an error writing it down, is that you wrote `module SomeMoudule` instead of `module SomeModule`

Comment: Module methods (`def self.meth...`), as opposed to module instance methods (yes, a misnomer, but that's what they are called) cannot be executed with a class or an instance of the class as their receiver, after the class has `include`ed or `extend`ed their module. Their only use is being called on their module, such as those in the `Math` module (e.g., `Math.sin(r)`). In effect, they are treated as functions in non-OOP languages. `C.d #=> NoMethodError (undefined method 'd' for C:Class)` should therefore be no surprise. `C::B.d` displays `"hi there"` only because `A::B.d` does the same.

Comment: @Lomefin ah sorry that was a typo here. corrected it in the post.

Comment: As an aside, this is not the purpose of `NotImplementedError`. According to the [Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/NotImplementedError.html) `NotImplementedError` is: *"Raised when a feature is not implemented on the current platform. For example, methods depending on the `fsync` or `fork` system calls may raise this exception if the underlying operating system or Ruby runtime does not support them."* Using it in the provided fashion in `account_info` suggests that the platform cannot support this, which would be inappropriate and misleading in this case.

Comment: What should be used then?

Comment: @Jwan622 you can create your own error although usually when I see this "pattern" where you have to stub a method like that I ask myself is there a default available? In this case why not something simple like `"No Account Information Available for #{self.name}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the reference in this [article which explains include, extend, and prepend](https://medium.com/@leo_hetsch/ruby-modules-include-vs-prepend-vs-extend-f09837a5b073) and I found out that `extends` works with the Singleton class already so the `self` is unnecesary.

I made a small test with this code, which removes the `self` in the definition

```
module SomeModule
  module Account
    def account_info
      raise NotImplementedError
    end
  end
end

class MockClass
  extend SomeModule::Account
end

MockClass.account_info
```

And that raises NotImplementedError

Comment: As written, your module can be used to make account_info class or instance methods. If you intend your methods to only be class methods, I'd recommend using `include` and defining them as class methods within your module. `def self.included(base) base.extend ClassMethods end` then define your methods in `module ClassMethods` within SomeModule::Account. See [ActiveSupport::Concern](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) for an example of mixing instance methods, class methods, and code injection in a module.

Comment: This of course is the conventional way extending a module by a class. The fact that `Account` is defined within another module is not relevant. If `Account` is not to be `include`d anywhere in the program it would be simpler and clearer to define `account_info` as a module method, to be called `SomeModule::Account.account_info` rather than `extend`ing `SomeModule::Account` to enable `account_info` to be executed on `MockClass`.